# Android layout different when used as fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to create a layout to be used as a fragment.  However, it doesn't render the way I intend when inflated as a fragment.  When I use it as the main layout for an application, it works just fine:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.fazjaxton.apptest.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

[image: Application picture]

However, when I use the same layout as a fragment, the toolbar at the bottom is rendered off the bottom of the screen:

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <!--
    tools:context="net.fazjaxton.apptest.MainActivity">
    -->


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.fazjaxton.fragtest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance() {
            return new PlaceholderFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() { return 1; }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { return "title"; }
    }
}
```

[image: Fragment picture]

(I am using two different base projects from android studio.  The first is the Basic Activity, the second is the Tabbed Activity)

I am having trouble understanding why this is the case.  Do I need to compensate for the manual toolbar in the tabbed activity differently than the default toolbar in the basic activity?

Comment: Please explain why you put a Toolbar into the Fragment

Comment: are you sure the same fragment is showing up? just put some view (textview etc) in fragment_main.xml and see if it is the same fragment?

Comment: @junaidhafeez - I have tested and it is.  I have also set a bottom margin on the toolbar, which causes it to appear higher on the screen.  This is how I know it is rendered off the bottom (without the margin).

Answer (score 0):

You have two views with id `R.id.toolbar`: one in **activity_main.xml**, the other in **fragment_main.xml**. This may cause the issue.